# Boton ID, Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Necesito obtener de manera string webmethod ASP.NET C# el Id del boton html.

Hasta el momento tengo lo siguiente y me funciona para obtener el valor del textbox.

```
            <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dashboard.ks.Dashboard.ks.Test" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head id="Head1" runat="server">
                <title></title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

            <script type = "text/javascript">
                function ShowCurrentTime() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Test.aspx/myFunction",
                        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        //alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            }
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[0]; 
                document.getElementById('<%=Label2.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[1]; 
                document.getElementById('<%=Label3.ClientID %>').innerHTML = response.d[2]; 
            }
            </script> 
            </head>
            <body style = "font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt">
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
            Your Name : 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" 
                onclick = "ShowCurrentTime()" />
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Aquí estoy Change my mind"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Aquí estoy Change my mind again"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Aquí estoy Change my mind once again"></asp:Label>

            </div>
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```

El codebehind

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Web.UI;
            using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
            using System.Data.SqlClient;
            using System.Configuration;
            using System.Data;


            namespace Dashboard.ks.Dashboard.ks
            {
                public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
                {
                    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                    {

                    }



                    //public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
                    //{
                    //    return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
                    //        + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    //}
                    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

                    public static Array myFunction(string name)
                    {

                        string[] a = new string[3];
                        a[0] = "value 1" + name;
                        a[1] = "value 2" + name;
                        a[2] = "value 3" + name;

                        return a;

                    }

                }
            }
```

Supongamos que el string "name" que está siendo capturado en:

```
                        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
```

quiero que el name diga: btnGetTime

Ayuda con esto?, como debo modificar el Jquery?

O sea que el resultado final será:

Value 1btnGetTime
Value 2btnGetTime
Value 3btnGetTime

Aqui no agregué mas botones, pero dado el caso que agregue 2 o mas botones, tambien debe funcionar igual para con estos.

Value 1btnGetTimeB
Value 2btnGetTimeB
Value 3btnGetTimeB

Value 1btnGetTimeC
Value 2btnGetTimeC
Value 3btnGetTimeC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si defines varios botones

```
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" />
<input id="btnGetTime2" type="button" value="Show Current Time" />
<input id="btnGetTime3" type="button" value="Show Current Time" />
```

podrias enviar el nombre de que lanza la accion

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        $("[id*='btnGetTime']").click(function(){
            var buttonName = $(this).attr('id');
            ShowCurrentTime(buttonName);
        });

    });

    function ShowCurrentTime(buttonName) {

        var params = {
            name: buttonName
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/myFunction",
            data: params,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
            //alert(response.d);
        }
    });
    }
    function OnSuccess(response) {
        $('#<%=Label1.ClientID %>').html(response.d[0]); 
        $('#<%=Label2.ClientID %>').html(response.d[1]); 
        $('#<%=Label3.ClientID %>').html(response.d[2]); 
    }
</script>
```

a los diferentes botones le asocias el click de forma dinamica por eso el selector usando el `*=` tomando todos los botones que tengan el texto que definas.

[Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Comment: Me parece excelente, solo una cosa, como sería en el caso que el boton no inicia con ese nombre, sino , termina con ese nombre? ... Los botones se llaman: table1_btnCheck, table2_btnCheck, table3_btnCheck, table4_btnCheck

Comment: ahi agregue un detalle sobre el *=  como veras no afecta donde este el texto que definas en el selector

Comment: Gracias me funciono mucho, hice unos cambios para que fuera 100% funcional, borrando la variable var params, y metiendo el buttonName en data: '{name: "' + buttonName + '"}',